# Jagged array exceeding input c#

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

`

```
for(int i=0;i<jagged.Length;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<jagged[i].Length;i++)
{
jagged[i][j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
}
```

`
i want this piece of code to take 2 score inputs in jagged[0] and 3 score inputs in jagged[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZOxh.png) but it is taking 5 inputs in both the cases.

[jagged array input problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZOxh.png)

For "n" number of teams with "at" attempts, i want to store the scores of these teams in "at" attempts in the jagged array
example :
if used inputs n = 2 and at= 2 for the first team.
a jagged[2][2] should be created,
i want to store the scores in this way-
jagged[0] should be =  new int[2]; (which i did at line 15)
The lines starting from 21 are supposed to store these scores,
but when i run the program, it takes input of scores more than the Length.
What i want is -
jagged[0][0] should store the first score input
jagged[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZOxh.png) should store the second score input
and it should stop there. but it doesnt , it takes input 3 more times.(5 times total)

Similarly, the attempts for 2nd team is input as 3 and still it is taking the input 2 more times (5 times total)

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable on this site. Please post your code in your question text. To format it as code, prefix each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: Do not post an image of your code. Please [edit] your question and add a relevant code block, please.

Comment: You don't need second for loop of `for(int i =0 ; i<n;i++)`

Comment: I added a piece of code, Is it any helpful?

Comment: You're expected to add a [mcve]. That means that the code you provide needs to be sufficient for us to use it to reproduce your problem. If I paste the code you have provided into Visual Studio, I get errors telling me that `jagged` and `jag` don't exist. More specifically: from the code you have posted, it's unclear how `jagged` and `jag` are defined.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I need that for loop for Displaying the team number i.e Enter the score for team i+1 (1,2,3,4,...)

Comment: Put that inside `j` for loop

Comment: Thank you so much @ChetanRanpariya. I feel ashamed not figuring out such an easy thing. Thanks a lot again! :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are using a triple cicle, but you just need 2. Remove the k for cicle,and change the condition for the j cicle to j <jag[i].Length